# Visual studio professional 2015 - can't connect to VSO - SplitterDistance error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I'm running Visual Studio Professional 2015 on Windows 10, and I'm attempting to connect to Visual Studio Online using the "manage connections" feature from the team explorer.  Every time I click on Manage Connections \ Connect to Team Project, an error appears immediately above:

SplitterDistance must be between Panel1MinSize and Width - Panel2MinSize.

[image: error image link]

Based on researching this issue, this error appears in various forms in previous versions of Visual Studio, but it's not clear to me how to fix it in 2015. Here are a couple of things I tried...

- A "repair" of Visual Studio didn't improve the situation
- Switching the Source Control plugin selection from Microsoft git provider to Visual Studio Team Foundation Server didn't net anything different.

Is anyone aware of a patch/fix for this issue, or an alternative way to connect to VSO other than the Manage Connections \ Connect to Team Project feature?

Comment: What's the version number of your VS2015?

Comment: This bug has a looong history https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ee6abc76-f35a-41a4-a1ff-5be942ae3425/splitcontainer-panel-minsize-defect?forum=winformsdesigner

Comment: I get this when running (a hyper-v vm) on a 4k (3200x1800) screen with windows' UI scaling set to 200% (display settings). Dropping the host resolution back to 1920x1080 and restarting everything made this go away for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the workaround in this http://blogs.recneps.net/post/Issue-setting-up-Raspberry-Pi-Windows-10-IoT-core-and-Visual-Studio-on-a-Windows-10-VM for details.

Quote the steps here:

> Open up Team Foundation Server online at
>   .visualstudio.com. Click code, then navigate to the
>   project you want to open, click on the solution file which then opens
>   the solution in the web editor. Click the visual studio icon and VS
>   opens with the team project now in team explorer. Close VS and open it
>   again and your team project should still be  connected to team
>   explorer

Comment: This was a good workaround.  Note that "manage connections" still doesn't function correctly, but the solution remains bound to TFS and I verified round-tripping of files to/from the server.

Comment: Did anyone actually figure out a real solution to this? The workaround works, but I've updated VS and still no dice. I'm working with Microsoft's AX 2012, which requires VS2013 unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when connecting to a VM via hyper-v. I was connecting using a remote desktop connection and my resolution was 4k (3840x2160) with some scaling. The only way I could get rid of this problem was by shutting down the VM, then setting the resolution on the remote desktop connection to 1920x1080, and then powering up the VM again. Making the connection in Visual Studio to the repository and then restoring the resolution back to 3840x2160.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2015 UI does not manage the high resolution well. Most of us will use a full-screen RDP connection to the virtual machine, Windows takes the native resolution of your notebook by default, passes this to Visual Studio and this leads to the said error message. The full HD resolution of 1920 x 1080 already means trouble.

The solution is simple:

1. Sign off from the VM.
2. Change the RDP connection settings from the
   fullscreen to 1024x768.
3. Sign on to the VM.
4. Start Visual Studio and connect to the Team Explorer for the first time.
5. Close Visual Studio and let it save your preferences.

Next time, the error message will not occur even when connecting to another DevOps server.